# Using stan's multi_normal distribution

Tags: linear-regression, stan

I am trying to do a pooled Bayesian model of the type $\log(y)=\beta_1*\log(x_1)+\beta_2*\log(x_2)+\alpha$. I'm having problems sampling $\beta$ using stan's multi_normal distribution (I'm running it on rstan), and I get the following error message:

'**Error in stanc(filename, allow_undefined = TRUE) : 0
Syntax error in 'string', line 14, column 29 to column 35, parsing error:
Ill-formed expression. Expected a comma-separated list of expressions.**

I suspect there's some kind of syntax error when I run R's code checker, but I can't see the mistake. Below is the code. What I want in the end, is to get estimates for $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N; //number of observations
  int<lower=2> K; //number of explanatory variables
  matrix[N,K] x; //explanatory variables
  vector[N] y; //outcome
 }

parameters {
  vector[K] beta;
  real alpha;
  real sigma;
}

model {
  //priors
  beta ~ multi_normal(c(0,0),matrix(c(1,0.8,0.8,1),ncol=2));
  alpha ~ normal(0,10^10);
  sigma ~ uniform(0,100);
  // likelihood
  for (i in 1:N)
      log(y)[i] ~ normal(log(x[i,1])*beta[1]+log(x[i,2])*beta[2] + alpha, sigma);

generated quantities {
  vector[K] beta;
  real alpha;
  real sigma;
}
```

Comment: The line with the prior on `beta` is most likely the problem.  Using `c()` to specify a vector is R notation; for Stan, use [square brackets](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_19/reference-manual/vector-matrix-and-array-expressions.html) instead: `[1, 0.8, 0.8, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks A. S. K. that solved the problem. However, now there seems to be something wrong with the line where the distribution of log(y) is defined. I added curly brackets to the for loop, but it's still not working.

Comment: Does `log(y[i])` work?  But see also [this page](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/sampling-statements-section.html#user-transformed-variables) for an additional necessary step.